# how to find out secret service codes for android

Tags: stock-android, kernel, dialer-codes, open-source

I have a Spice Dream Uno (Android One) and none of the secret service codes I found on the internet (like *#*#197328640#*#* and *#*#7378423#*#*) work on it. Do I have to root my phone in order for these to work?

Is it possible to pull it from the source code (google has released the kernel source code)? Where should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Secret Codes](https://f-droid.org/wiki/page/fr.simon.marquis.secretcodes).

From the site:

> Secret Codes is an application that allows you to scan the secret codes available on your device through the dialer app.
>   The application will scan through all available secret codes on your device. Then you will be able to executes these secret codes and discover hidden functionalities.
>   In Android a secret code is defined by this pattern: *#*#code#*#*.

Comment: I tried out this app. It finds the various applications' codes but not the code for phone's service menu.

Comment: @svarog - that will only show application secret codes, it doesn't show any codes __for__ the phone. Link is useful and open sourced, but not correct for answer.